# How do I unsubscribe from a Firebase list in Angular2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am connecting to a Firebase list using

```
tasks: FirebaseListObservable<ITask[]>;

constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
  this.tasks = this.af.database.list("/tasks");
}
```

And now I want to cancel that connection, when my users logout.

I already tried `this.tasks.unsubscribe()`, but looks like the method is undefined (I tried this because FirebaseListObservable is an observable).

I also tried `this.tasks.off()` as suggested in the documentation, but it is also undefined.

Finally, I tried `this.tasks = null` and that works, but I'm not sure if that is the correct implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this.tasks` is an [Observable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/observable.md) not a [Subscription](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subscription.md) which is why you cannot unsubscribe.

If you are manually subscribing then you can:

```
let observable = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
let subscription = observable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

If you are using the [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html) then Angular will automatically unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. Based on the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.7/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L95), the observable will be unsubscribed if the value of the pipe changes to null, but this is not specified in the docs anywhere. I think a better option would be to explicitly destroy the components where you use the async pipe.

Comment: Perfect, I will destroy the components