# Ionic & AngularFireDatabase list result - Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, observable, angularfire2

I am trying to get data from Firebase by the `list` function and to use it in Json format (to load markers on my Google Map). But I'm facing an issue with the returned `snapshots`: *Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'*

My imports:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

And the code snippet with the error:

```
markers: Observable<any[]>;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
      public geolocation: Geolocation, 
      public db: AngularFireDatabase) { 

        this.markers = this.db.list("empresa/", {preserveSnapshot: true})
          .map(snapshots => {
            return snapshots.map(snapshot => { // this second .map displays the error
              return snapshot.val();    
            })
            .subscribe((marcas)=> {
              console.log(marcas);
            });
        });
      }
```

Because of this, I think, the `subscribe` does not display anything on the console. I also tried to import in some different ways the rxjs, as in this link [Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208801/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse), but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a migration issue - [since AF 5.0](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#updating-firebaselistobservable-to-angularfirelistt) `list` returns an `AngularFireList<T>` service, not `FirebaseListObservable`, you have to call [an action](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#angularfireaction---action-based-api) on it to stream data into an observable collection, e.g.:

```
    const subscription = this.db.list("empresa/").snapshotChanges()
      .map(snapshots => {
        return snapshots.map(snapshot => snapshot.payload.val());
      })
      .subscribe(values => {
        console.log(values);
        this.markers = values;
      });
```

Note also that the `subscribe` is chained after the outer `map`, not the inner as in your example; and `this.markers` are being assigned results inside the subscription, so you have to change their type from `Observable<any[]>` to `any[]` (or whatever they are, just not observable).

See [3. Retrieving data as lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md) in the docs for details; there's an example at the end of the page on using the listed items inside an angular template with async pipe, where you don't need to `subscribe`, then you'd keep `this.markers` as `Observable<any[]>` and the rest would be:

```
this.markers = this.db.list("empresa/").snapshotChanges()
  .map(snapshots => {
    return snapshots.map(snapshot => snapshot.payload.val());
  });
```

This is preferred as the async pipe manages the subscription for you (because if you are subscribing manually you should also [`unsubscribe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42336977/8555393)).

Comment: How can I retrieve the data in the console (just like I did using `subscribe` above)?

Comment: You should subscribe after the outer map, updated the answer.

Comment: I asked because doing this, the "this.markers" shows the error: `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.`

Comment: With the manual subscription the situation changes a bit, updated the answer.